# How to spawn a new process in NodeJS and redirect stderr to stdout?

Tags: node.js, bash

I need to spawn a new process in NodeJS. Its stderr should be redirected to its stdout (the same as `2>&1` in bash).

**proc.js**

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var opt = {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']};
var proc = child_process.spawn('./myscript', [], opt);
proc.stderr.pipe(proc.stdout);
proc.stdout.on('data', function (buf) {
    console.log('stdout', buf.toString());
});
proc.on('error', function (...args) {
    console.log('error', args);
});
proc.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
    console.log('exit', code, signal);
});
proc.on('close', function (code, signal) {
    console.log('close', code, signal);
});
```

**myscript**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 111
echo 222 >&1
echo 333 >&2
echo 444
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. There is no *333* in the output:

```
stdout 111
222
444

exit 0 null
close 0 null
```

Comment: from a practical perspective... why?  Why would you want to control this inside your script, rather than via the Linux redirects?

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem is you are piping the child (proc) stderr to it own stdout, rather than your own stdout.  proc.stdout is a source, not a sink, so it can't take input from another pipe.

Maybe what you want is, instead of:

```
proc.stderr.pipe(proc.stdout);
```

this:

```
proc.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);
```

process.stdout is your parent process stdout, which is a sink, so it can take proc.stderr, which is a source.

Comment: Or in node terms, proc.stdout is a ReadableStream, while process.stdout is a WriteableStream

Comment: I clearly have a way with words.  I was going to use gazintah and gazoutah, but settled on sink and source. :-)